# F5 making a noise not running, Ctrl+F5 running fine, F11 acts exactly like F5?

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2013

In visual studio, for years i have been running programs with <kbd>F5</kbd> and Debugging with <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd>, now when i click those there is an "Error" noise and nothing happens.
When i run the program with <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> it worked perfectly. 
At first i though is because the 2010 VS so i downloaded the 2013 VS and its acting the same there but without the noise.
VS2010 after trying the above and VS2013 after trying the above pics attached.

[image: VS2010 after trying the above]

[image: VS2013 after trying the above]

Comment: One of you colleagues has swapped your keytops :)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Keyboard options for your Visual Studio instance? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx

Comment: Click on Tools > Options. Then click Environment, then Keyboard. Scroll the list till you find "Debug.Start". Make sure the Shortcut is set to "F5"

Comment: @icemanind its not working. although even when i click on the buttons for those actions it acts the same so the shortcuts are alright.

Comment: What does the Output window say?

Comment: There is no output window(console)

Comment: it might be time to write a small/simple program to read the raw keyboard inputs.  Then use that program to assure the keyboard has not failed.  BTW: have you recently upgraded the OS and/or the keyboard-terminal driver?  Has the environment variable that indicates the keyboard type changed?

Comment: For your last 2 questions, no. and how i write the program you mentioned?

Comment: Do you use a laptop? Maybe the F-keys are used with the "fn" keys (for example turn wlan on/off)

Comment: More info: if im quick enough after the F5,F10,F11 if i click F6 the "Do you want to stop debugging window" is pooped. Im frustrated , please help me guys.

Comment: @katz No, its not a laptop. And i written , if i click 'Debug' -> 'Step into' or 'Step over' its the same error sound, so it has nothing to do with the F-s.

Comment: So it seems i cant debug.Only run the programs with Ctr+F5. Anyone?

Comment: Does it work if you go click on Debug, then Start Debugging?

Comment: @icemanind no.it makes the same error noise and all the things i wrote above.

Comment: Have you tried to create a brand new simple application?  Does it work then?  Are you sure you're in Debug configuration (drop down at top of screen)?

Comment: I have tried another simple application and yes im sure.

Comment: Should i delete all and install from the start? i also repaired the VS2010 file and reinstalled it and it still not working.

Comment: the error in the output window is: 'WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.Module

Comment: @leppie the putput you asked..

Comment: That is the Debug output, show the Build output.

Comment: @leppie How do i get to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,my solution was to format my HDD and download VS...